# AS3 - Get MovieClip instance name onClick

Tags: actionscript-3

I've a row of MovieClips with the instance names holder0 to holder7. How can I get the holder name of the MovieClip by click?

Thanks for tips.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var mc:MovieClip;
for (var i:int = 0; i<8; i++) {
    mc = this["holder"+i];
    mc.buttonMode = true;
    mc.mouseChildren = false;
    mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
}

function clickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
    trace(e.target.name);
}
```